# Laravel eloquent querying with multiple relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have four tables which is `departments`, `users`, `items`, `items_inventories`

The relationship is like this:

A `user` has a assigned `department`.
An `item` has a assigned `department`. `item_inventories` has many items.

Structure:

```
users
->id
->name
->password
->access_type (department_id)

departments
->id
->name

items
->id
->name
->department_id

items_inventories
->id
->item_id
->qty
```

My models:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Http\Models\Department', "id", "department_id");
    }
}


class ItemsInventory extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Http\Models\Item', "id", "item_id");
    }
}
```

In my `items_inventories` how do I query all items that belongs to a specific department? Since `items` has already a relationship to `departments`, How do I query like: select all items in items_inventories where item department_id is equal to 3?

My goal is, I have a user who is logged in, and I can access the assigned department to him/her via `access_type` (department_id) when my page loads, I want to list only items in the `items_inventories` that is assigned to his/her department. I already checked: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties` but can't seem to find something that matches my requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are a bit confusing. The table structure says that `items` belong to `departments` and `item inventories` belong to `items`. I've based the relationship on your table structure and how you can achieve your desired result. You might want to check on your relationship once more to verify how exactly you want it to pan out. As for the current relationship, my models should give you an idea.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Department', 'access_type');
    }
}

class Department extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Item');
    }

    public function itemInventory()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Http\Models\ItemsInventory', 'App\Http\Models\Item');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Department');
    }

    public function itemInventory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\ItemsInventory');
    }
}

class ItemsInventory extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Item');
    }
}
```

Controller logic

```
$department_id = 3;

$itemInventory = ItemsInventory::whereHas('item', function ($query) use ($department_id) {
    $query->where('department_id', $department_id);
})->get();

// With user:department relation and department:iteminventory 'hasManyThrough' relation.

$itemInventory = $user->department()->itemInventory;
```